# Zappa with Docker don't found handler

Tags: python, docker, zappa

I tried to use zappa docs to use Zappa with Docker. But the doc is outdated and not work.

There is a [tutorial](https://ianwhitestone.work/zappa-serverless-docker/) about how to use zappa with docker and a suggestions about how to use with pipenv that don't work too.

I tried to change the dockerfile to it:

```yaml
FROM python:3.8 as base

# Setup env
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1

FROM base AS python-deps

# Install pipenv and compilation dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

RUN apt-get install postgresql-client libjpeg-dev -y

RUN apt-get install gcc libc-dev musl-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev -y

# Install python dependencies in /.venv
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy
#RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps


FROM base AS runtime

# Copy virtual env from python-deps stage
COPY --from=python-deps /.venv /.venv
ENV PATH="/.venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY . .

ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task/"

COPY ./ $FUNCTION_DIR

# Grab the zappa handler.py and put it in the working directory
RUN ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH=$( \
    python -c "from zappa import handler; print (handler.__file__)" \
    ) \
    && echo $ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH \
    && cp $ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH $FUNCTION_DIR

CMD ["handler.lambda_handler"]
```

and I use the command `docker build -t lambda-docker-flask:latest .` and It works fine, but when I try to run `docker run -p 9000:8080 lambda-docker-flask:latest` I received the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "handler.lambda_handler": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

I was googling a lot about docker and some insights was to change
`CMD ["handler.lambda_handler"]`
to
`CMD handler.lambda_handler`

But I receive a different error:
`/bin/sh: 1: handler.lambda_handler: not found`

I would like a suggestion about what I can do. The code is available here:
https://github.com/LeonardoFurtado/zappa-docker

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the incorrect base image; it should be `amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.8` instead of `python:3.8`.